# converting html tags into jade node template

Tags: javascript, html, css, pug

so I'm having trouble converting html tags into jade node template engine

the html output template that I want to display is this

```
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-hover"> Dropdown
      <ul class="dropdown-hover-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </a>
```

I'm using [html2jade.org](http://html2jade.org) which is a jade node templates converter for html

when I convert the HTML it went with ouput like this

```
a.dropdown-hover(href='#') Dropdown
    ul.dropdown-hover-menu
        li
          a(href='#') Dropdown menu
        li
          a(href='#') Dropdown menu2
```

then I go to my IDE text editor and paste it, but somehow the output was not according to my needs at all and it goes like this...

```
<a class="dropdown-hover" href="#">Dropdown</a>
<ul class="dropdown-hover-menu"><a class="dropdown-hover" href="#">
</a><li><a class="dropdown-hover" href="#"></a><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Dropdown menu2</a></li>
</ul>
```

why the output like this? please help me

Answer (score 0):

and tried to use another editor, or check with any extension saves your file, checking in your editor I'm fine preserved

Comment: sublime, ide phpshtorm, aptana studio the ones I use

Comment: and if all the same in another editor will have the same problem, check the enlargement of sohryanyaemogo file is often the case that the file is not properly stored

Comment: okay let me try it.. thank you so much for your help cheers :)